# jQuery .NET webservice call, parameter based on value in table cell

Tags: .net, jquery, web-services

I have a web service that wish to call, and I want to pass a parameter to it based on a value in a table cell. The table is rendered by a Repeater Control.

The idea is to show a div with data returned from the database call, performed by the webservice, when I hover over the table rows.

The javascript call looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr.rows").hover(function() {
        //alert('Test');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{ madvare: '" + $('span#MadLogMadVare').val() + "'}",
            url: "HoverBox.asmx/GetDetails",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                //alert('Success Test');
                var Madvare = data.d;
                $('#DetailsBox').html(
      ('<p><strong>' + Madvare.MadLogMadVare + "</strong><br />"))

            }
        });
    });
});
```

The call never reaches the success function, so my guess is that I'm not getting the value correctly from the Table cell...

Any ideas how to get the value from the rendered Table cell?

I thought I wolud add the Webservice code:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
```

[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class HoverBox : WebService
{
    public HoverBox()
    {
    }

```
private static string _connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

[WebMethod]
public static MadLog GetDetails(string madvare)
{

    MadLog _madlog = new MadLog();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM frisk_madlog WHERE frisk_madlogmadvare = @frisk_madlogmadvare";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("frisk_madlogmadvare", madvare);

            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    _madlog.MadLogID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["frisk_madlogID"]);
                    _madlog.MadLogUserID = (Guid)(rdr["frisk_madloguserID"]);
                    _madlog.MadLogMadVare = rdr["frisk_madlogmadvare"].ToString();
                    _madlog.MadLogKalorier = (double)(rdr["frisk_madlogkalorier"]);
                    _madlog.MadLogMaengde = (double)(rdr["frisk_madlogmaengde"]);
                    _madlog.MadLogDato = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["frisk_madlogdato"]);
                    _madlog.MadLogKategori = rdr["frisk_madlogkategori"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return _madlog;
}
```

}

Comment: first are you sure that there is no errors happen on the webservice code side?

Comment: No, I'm not getting any errors from the webservice code...
I tested the dataaccess code directly, and it returns the data I need...

Comment: but not receiving the right data?

Comment: Right. I just tried passing a hardcoded parametervalue to the webservice like this - data: "{ madvare: Rice", - with no result...

Comment: you mean that you sent the data hardcoded and also the success didn't call?

Comment: Yes, instead of trying to get it from the Table cell like this:
data: "{ madvare: '" + $('span#MadLogMadVare').val() + "'}"
I did this:
data: "{ madvare: Rice}". The hover event fires corrctly, so I starting to think something is wrong with my webservice, though it looks allright, plus, like I said, the data access code works fine. The webservice returns an object, so maybe I'm not handling it correctly?

Comment: did you check my answer below?

Comment: Yes, I tried adding a failure function, but i get no response from the web service at all. I then tried to call a simple WebMethod that just returned a string, and that worked fine. The data I'm returning is a custom business object, so I guess the question is if I'm handling that object correctly. According to the articles I've read, it should be right. But ofcourse, it's not :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from first look

in this line:

```
data: "{ madvare: '" + $('span#MadLogMadVare').val() + "'}",
```

put a space in the selector to be like this:

```
data: "{ madvare: '" + $('span #MadLogMadVare').val() + "'}",
```

Also try to add error and timeout functions to debug whats happening:

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options